# looping sublist in lists

Tags: python, list, loops

I'm looking for help for the following problem
the program I'm  trying to build does the following:

first stage:
I'm solving a non linear equation with two values

second stage:
doing this sequence n time to get a series of answers

stage three:
I need to loop through each and every one of the answers separately, and apply it to another similar function as the first stage n times as well. the problem is the I note able to loop through the answers for the third stage. I tried to insert the answers I get in the first stage into a list of lists and and loop through that, but I don't get the right answers

Are there any suggestions how can I apply this kind of thing?

```
    Tin_segment = [650.]
    Q=[0]
    tstorage=[100.]

    def f(variables):
        (Tout, Q) = variables
        first_eq = 3600 * Q - 96645 * 1.2 * (Tin_segment[-1] - Tout)
        second_eq = 3600 * Q - 87.2 * 150 * ((Tin_segment[-1] + Tout) / 2 - tstorage[-1])
         return [first_eq, second_eq]


    n = 7
    def solve_init():
       for _ in range(n):
          solution = opt.fsolve(f, (1, 1))
          Tin_segment.append(solution[0].round(2))
          Q.append(solution[1].round(2))

   solve_init()
```

this is the first stage and I get some thing like this

`[650.0, 591.28, 538.83, 491.98, 450.13, 412.75, 379.36, 349.53]`

i need to take each value from this list and run it again through the function above n times.
i tired the following -  separating each value from the above into a sublist:

```
    n=1
    tout_segment = [Tin_segment[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(Tin_segment), n)]
```

to get this:

`[[650.0], [591.28], [538.83], [491.98], [450.13], [412.75], [379.36], [349.53]]`

and then loop again to add the answers to every sublist, but with no success

Comment: what means `loop again` ? Better show code which you use for this and expected result. Maybe you need `for item in tout_segment: item.append(value)` but you didn't show what you tried and what result you expect so we can't help you.

Comment: I don't understand why you create flat `Tin_segment` - maybe you could reate directly nested value - maybe it needs only to change some intendations and first create list with `[650.0]` and later append this list to global list.

Comment: and better create minimal working code with example data and all imports. It help to run code, see result, test modifications.

Comment: hi thank for your answer. the reason is as following:
the calculation has more then one stage: the first stage is used to get the initial values.
these initial values are then used again, using a similar function, and get a separate list, for each and every initial value

Comment: I think you have to second loop but with two `for`-loops. First to get elemen from list, second to use it n-times. But I have no idea what finall result you epxcet so I don't know if it is good direction. You should show expected result.

Comment: and you could add all `import` and other needed elements so we could simply copy and run it.

Comment: and you should send `Tin_segment[-1]` and `tstorage[-1]` to `f(variables)` as argument - and not use hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what result you want but I would do

```
import scipy.optimize as opt

# --- functions ---

def f(variables):
    (Tout, Q, Tin, ts) = variables
    first_eq = 3600 * Q - 96645 * 1.2 * (Tin - Tout)
    second_eq = 3600 * Q - 87.2 * 150 * ((Tin + Tout) / 2 - ts)
    return [first_eq, second_eq, 0, 0]


def solve_init():
    global Tin_segment
    
    item = Tin_segment
    
    for _ in range(n):
        first, second, _, _ = opt.fsolve(f, (1, 1, item[-1], tstorage[-1]))
        item.append(first.round(2))
        Q.append(second.round(2))

    print(Tin_segment)
    print('-----')
        
    Tin_segment = [[x] for x in item]
    
    for item in Tin_segment:
        for _ in range(n):
            first, second, _, _ = opt.fsolve(f, (1, 1, item[-1], tstorage[-1]))
            item.append(first.round(2))
            Q.append(second.round(2))

    print(Tin_segment)
    print('-----')

# --- main ---

n = 7

Tin_segment = [ 650. ]
Q = [0]
tstorage = [100.]

solve_init()
```

Result

```
[650.0, 591.28, 538.83, 491.98, 450.13, 412.75, 379.36, 349.53]
-----
[
[650.0, 591.28, 538.83, 491.98, 450.13, 412.75, 379.36, 349.53], 
[591.28, 538.83, 491.98, 450.13, 412.75, 379.36, 349.53, 322.89], 
[538.83, 491.98, 450.13, 412.75, 379.36, 349.53, 322.89, 299.09], 
[491.98, 450.13, 412.75, 379.36, 349.53, 322.89, 299.09, 277.83], 
[450.13, 412.75, 379.36, 349.53, 322.89, 299.09, 277.83, 258.84], 
[412.75, 379.36, 349.53, 322.89, 299.09, 277.83, 258.84, 241.88], 
[379.36, 349.53, 322.89, 299.09, 277.83, 258.84, 241.88, 226.73], 
[349.53, 322.89, 299.09, 277.83, 258.84, 241.88, 226.73, 213.2]
]
```

Comment: thank you very much. it seems to be working